# Node-inspector does not attach itself to application

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, vagrant, node-inspector, node-debugger

I have tried launching node-inspector using:

```
 node-inspector
 node-inspector &
```

I have tried launching my app using:

```
 node --debug ./bin/www
 node --debug-brk ./bin/www
```

I am running the app from a `vagrant` box from which I have used port forwarding for the port 3000 and running the `node-inspector` on my windows PC.I have tried disabling all my Chrome extensions,I have tried removing and reinstalling `node-inspector` as well.I have tried adding `debugger` messages to my files.

I always get this window when I open node-inspector,it does not load any of the applications files for me to set breakpoints.[Here is a screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/nflil8yoi4w3k8u/Screenshot%202014-10-31%2009.03.08.png?dl=0) of node-inspector.

I have also tried disabling my antivirus(Avast) and that does not work,I have tried forwarding the port `5858`.

I have tried starting the default debugger,it just says `connecting...`:

```
  node debug localhost:5858
```

How can I understand what the problem is and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to forward port 5858 as well from your vagrant box to pc. Alternatively, start node-inspector inside vagrant and forward its web port ( 8080 by default )

Comment: Can I start both the `app` and `node-inspector` within the `vagrant` box at the same time?I am already forwarding the port 5858,that does not seem to have worked for me

Comment: Yes, you can. You only mentioned you are forwarding port 3000

Comment: After the post,I thought,I started forwarding `5858` also,can you tell me what `web-port` and `debug-port` are,I have decieded that I do not want to block 8080,so I want to run it on `3007`,so I am trying `vagrant@precise32:~/app$ node-debug ./bin/www --debug-port 3007 --web-port 3000
Node Inspector is now available from http://localhost:8080/debug?port=5858
Debugging `./bin/www` debugger listening on port 5858`

Comment: node-inspector talks to both debugger agent using v8 debugger protocol over tcp:5858 and to web browser ( node-inspector itself acts as web server for that) 5858 here is debugger port and 8080 - web port (port you pointing your browser to connect to inspector).

Comment: It looks like you need to pass port numbers before your script so node-debug treats them as its own parameters and not script parameters: `node-debug --debug-port 3007 --web-port 3000 ./bin/www`

Comment: @AndeySidorov I have got this up and running,I was able to find my real error...I got the 8080 port forwarded as well,I used the `node-debug ./bin/www`,then it worked.